# I have file which name is in Japanese (Unicode) language so how can I get backup using pg_dump in postgres

Tags: postgresql, unicode, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to get a backup of my data base in a file with a Unicode character name in Postgres using `pg_dump`.

But `pg_dump` doesn't support Unicode.

I gives me this error:

```
pg_dump : [archiver] could not open output file 
" D:\????.sal" : Invalid Argument
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question if you made mistakes in posting

Comment: What OS are you using? How do you invoke `pg_dump`?